# How does function overloading work at run-time, and why overload?

Tags: c++, runtime, switch-statement, member, overloading

Let's say I have a class named ClothingStore. That class has 3 member functions, that point a visitor to the right department of the store. Member functions are ChildrenDept, MenDept and WomenDept, depending on whether the visitor is a child, a man or a woman.

Function overloading can be used to make 3 functions that have same name, say, PointToDept, but take different input argument ( child, man, woman ).

What is actually happening on run-time when program is executing ?

My guess is that compiler adds switch statements to the program, to select the right member function. But that makes me wonder - is there any benefit in terms of program performance when using overloaded functions, instead of making your own function with switch statements? Again, my only conclusion on that part is code readability. Thank you.

Comment: The compiler sees three different functions just as though they had been differently named.  Which function to call is worked out at each call site by (the compiler) looking at the types of the arguments and "pattern matching" with the types of the parameters.  There is no switch statement.  The call is simply to the unique function with matching parameters.  If the compiler can't find a match (because the C++ rules for overload resolution are not met), you get a compile time error message.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism#Early_binding

Comment: "why overload?" - because it lets you write client code that doesn't need to change its call to the overloaded function even if the type of data it's providing changes.  That's convenient for normal client code - just in case during development or maintenance programming it evolves to use another type, but it's crucial when the client is say a template that could accept from its caller any of the types in question: if the template can call the overloaded function using identical source code, one form of polymorphism (overloads) cleanly supports the other (templates).

Comment: Function overloading is resolved at compile-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Gene's comment:

> The compiler sees three different functions just as though they had been differently named.

In the case of most compilers, they are differently named. This used to be called [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) where the function name is prefixed by return type and suffixed by the parameter types.

Answer (score 7):

> My guess is that compiler adds switch statements to the program, to select the right member function.

That's a bad guess. C++ is a statically typed language. The type of a variable does not change at runtime. This means the decision as to which non-polymorphic overload to call is one that can always be made at compile time. Section 13.3 in the standard, *Overload resolution*, ensures that this is the case. There's no reason to have a runtime decision when that decision can be made at compile time. The runtime cost of having a non-polymorphic overloaded function in most implementations is zero. The only exception might be a C++ interpreter.

Answer (score 6):

> How does function overloading work at run-time

It doesn't. It works at compile-time. A call to an overloaded function is no different at runtime from a call to a non-overloaded function.

> and why overload? ...  is there any benefit in terms of program performance when using overloaded functions, instead of making your own function with switch statements?

Yes. There is no runtime overhead at all, compared with 'making your own function with switch statements'.